# Connecting to an API endpoint to gather data with python

Tags: python, api, endpoint

Hi I am trying to extract information from this API endpoint: https://graphql.icy.tools/graphql
Im trying to fetch the trending collections as shown here: https://docs.icy.tools/developer-api/common-use-cases/fetch-trending-collections
To do so Im just using this simple code:

```html
import requests
import json

url = "https://graphql.icy.tools/graphql?query=TrendingCollections"
response= requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```

However after running it I just get an error in form of a json.
Is this because the parameter TrendingCollections is not recognized by the API, if so does someone know whats the actual value that I need to use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```html
import json
import requests

# Define the endpoint URL
endpoint = "https://graphql.icy.tools/graphql"

# Define the query
query = """
query TrendingCollections {
  trendingCollections(orderBy: SALES, orderDirection: DESC) {
    edges {
      node {
        address
        ... on ERC721Contract {
          name
          stats {
            totalSales
            average
            ceiling
            floor
            volume
          }
          symbol
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
"""

# Make the POST request to the endpoint
response = requests.post(endpoint, json={'query': query})

# Parse the JSON response
data = json.loads(response.text)

# Print the data
print(data)
```

This code made with python worked and retrieved all data!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).